# CSS for uniform thumbnail sizing

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have thumbnail product images that are in different aspect ratios and sizes. This is a marketplace app so sellers will load images in various sizes. I want to resize to make them fit within the thumbnail grid that I have.

The below css does the job for the most part. But images are top aligned. I want them bottom or middle aligned. `vertical-align` doesn't work for some reason.

See the second item at the demo site [mktdemo.outfitadditions.com](http://mktdemo.outfitadditions.com).

Is there a better way of doing this? I've tried some JS plugins too but they didn't work right.

I want the css to be responsive. I'm using Paperclip to resize images to be 200x200 i.e. the largest possible size in the aspect ratio that fits within 200x200. So if an image is in landscape size, the width is shorter than the height which throws things off. Thats why the css below.

```
.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding: 80% 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

.thumbnail img
{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.caption {

  h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }

  p {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 4px;
  }

position: relative;
top: -7px;
padding: 3px;
background-color: #f0f0f0;

}
```

my html.erb:

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="row">
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="thumbnail" > 
           <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive"), listing, data: { no_turbolink: true } %> 
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <h3><%= link_to listing.name.downcase.titleize, listing, data: { no_turbolink: true } %></h3>
            <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p>
        </div> 
     </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
 <p><%= will_paginate @listings, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %></p>
</div>
```

my model code with paperclip/imagemagick options.

```
has_attached_file :image, 
                  :styles => { :medium => "200x200>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

Comment: Try setting some standard height and width to your wrapper div..

Comment: It won't be responsive.

Comment: Give a standard height and width to your images then. Anyway, every iamges will be bound to an <img> tag right?

Comment: I resize to 200x200 but see demo site. See first and second images. The resize depends on whether it is landscape or portrait. How do I center align the second image in the demo?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

A relatively simple fix (apart from the `ImageMagick` options detailed by `Nitin Verma`), is to create a CSS "wrapper", which you can then put the image into. This wrapper / container can be responsive, and works to give your image height or width, hiding the rest:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5qzq14cg/)

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <%= image_tag "your_image.png" %>
</div>

#css
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.thumbnail img {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
}
```

You can then style the image height / width through the `.thumbnail` class. This will give you the ability to determine the size of the image you have.

We tend to use this method for *styling*, and the `ImageMagick` sizing to create smaller images. You have to remember that you'll never get the same proportions as images, and as such you need to be able to give the best styling, regardless of their size.

The CSS above will do this, whilst ImageMagick will provide you with the ability to create a lesser-resoluton image, making the rendering process more efficient

Comment: I tried similar solutions but fixed px are not responsive.

Comment: What about %, that's responsive

Answer (score -1):

If you are using paperclip then you can do it at the time of thumbnail generation itself. As it's uses image-magick for all image manipulation. Image-magick have many options for image manipulation. Below code is for image with transparent background. It automatic append transparent background if aspect ratio not like desired one.

```
has_attached_file :logo,
  :default_url => "/images/no-logo.png",
  :styles => {:thumb =>  ['100x100>', :png]},
  :convert_options => {:thumb => '-size 100x100 xc:transparent +swap -gravity center -composite'},
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => XXXXX,
    :secret_access_key => XXXXXXX
  },
  :path => ":attachment/:id.:extension"
```

You can also crop it from centre if you want like this :

```
has_attached_file :image,
  styles: {
    thumb: '100x100^',
    medium: '200x200^'
  },
  convert_options: {
    thumb: " -gravity center -crop '100x100+0+0'",
    medium: " -gravity center -crop '200x200+0+0'"
  },
```

Comment: thanks, I'm trying this out. can you tell me what the convert_options line does?

Comment: Yes sure. As paperclip uses imagemagick for thumbnail genaration. If you want to resize image with imagemagick you need to type command like `-size 100x100` By covert option we can append some sort of extra option that we can pass to imagemagick. many option you can find here http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

Comment: when i include the convert option line, I get an error saying image cannot be processed. When I remove the options line, the image loads but still the same alignment issue. I updated my post with my current paperclip code.

Comment: Instead of :all try use thumb in concert option. like : `:convert_options => {:thumb => '-size 100x100 xc:transparent +swap -gravity center -composite', 
:medium => '-size 200x200 xc:transparent +swap -gravity center -composite
},`

Comment: Still get an error saying image cannot be processed. I'm using imagemagick 6.8.9. Will look at docs.

Comment: try run this command `convert image.gif -resize 300x250 -size 300x250 xc:transparent +swap -gravity center -composite image-small.gif` on your local. If it's not producing any error then there is no problem from imagemagick . For this put any image with name image.gif in folder from where you running this command

Comment: I started adding options one by one. The error happens with the +swap option. Without that, the image processes but I still have the same alignment issue. Per docs, this command is not available in newer versions. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#fill

Comment: Okay so there must be something else for this. I am checking. I am having 6.6.9-7 version and it's working as expected

Comment: try use http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#backdrop first use it on your console.

Comment: I'm going to post this again. Thanks for helping me narrow it down to imagemagick.